# Windows Desktop doesn't show up on WSL

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I just recently set up WSL with Ubuntu 18.04 on my new windows computer. I know that to access my windows files from the linux side, the `C:\` drive is mapped to `/mnt/c`. When I try to `cd` to `/mnt/c/Users/malik22/Desktop`, however, I get a `No such file or directory error`. I access my window `Downloads`, `Documents`, etc. just fine from the linux side, but for some reason `Desktop` seems to be the only one not present.

I've been using WSL for over a year now on my old computer and have never run into this issue. Any ideas?

Comment: Well, check using cmd.exe if the Desktop folder was renamed or moved for example to be backed up by OneDrive. I, for example, don't see Desktop folder because I moved it to another drive and changed the location in Desktop properties

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your Desktop is backed up in your OneDrive it won't show up in your user directory.

You can either create a symbolic link as mentioned below by @raghav-malik or else choose to not back up your Desktop (you can instead back up your Documents directory).

Comment: That ended up being it; its backed up to OneDrive so its under the OneDrive folder. I think I'll make a symbolic link to it to avoid having to deal with that

Comment: @RaghavMalik Can you let me know what you did in the end? I have my desktop backed up to my University OneDrive and I have any important folders such as assignments etc stored there (on desktop). Did you just stop backing up of desktop and just back-up your documents instead? Also, can you explain more about the symbolic link and how you implemented that? Thanks

Comment: I used a command like this: 
`mklink /d Desktop "OneDrive - purdue.edu\ECNDATA\Desktop"`
This creates a directory called "Desktop" that just links to the onedrive backup of the desktop, allowing me to `cd` into it from both windows and WSL. Note its important that you run that command from CMD and not WSL

Comment: And so you created that link in your User Directory? Did you stop your OneDrive from backing up your desktop too?

Comment: Nope, OneDrive can keep backing it up into that folder, the symbolic link will stay updated. Yes I created that in my user directory